# Как сделать фиксированный подвал для сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, mobile-development

есть следующая задача:
На сайте есть фиксированный подвал (фиксированная высота, position: fixed и фиксированные отступы)
При скроллинге вверх подвал появляется, при скроллинге вниз—исчезает
В компьютерной версии все работает безупречно
В мобильной версии есть такой момент: когда скроллишь вверх, верхняя строка браузера опускается, когда скроллишь вниз—она убирается, соответственно размеры экрана меняются, а подвал съезжает
Конкретного события для такого поведения я не знаю, но оно попадает в touchmove
Страница довольно лёгкая, так что проверять каждое событие touchmove я могу себе позволить
Вопрос в другом: как в случае изменения размера экрана (onresize не подходит, событие ещё не выполнилось, пока что идёт только постепенное скрытие верхней строки браузера—соответственно в этот маленький промежуток классический onscroll тоже не работает) прибить подвал к низу страницы?
Потому что все innerheight, clientheight, getboundingclientrect и т.д. показывают высоту, которая была ДО начала исчезания верхней строки браузера и соответственно дают корявый результат

Comment: Приведите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Как у вас задано положение блока? У меня получилось повторить описаное поведение только если задавать положение блока через `top`. При `bottom` блок всегда был на месте.

Comment: У меня как раз только через top<footer></footer>
<style>
footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 100vw:
    top: 70vh;
}
</style>

Comment: Сейчас гляну, может Вы и правы

Comment: Спасибо), глупая ошибка